# Construct an orthonormal base given only one vector in 3d

Tags: 3d, vector-graphics, radix

I'm looking for a simple and efficient way to solve the following problem:

I have one vector in 3d and I want to get an orthonormal base (**x**, **y**, **z**) where one of the base vectors (let's say **x**) is the given vector. So I'm looking for two vectors, perpendicular to each other, that are also perpendicular to my given vector.

I know that this has infinite many solutions, but I don't care which one I get, as long as it satisfies the above requirements and getting it is simple and efficient.

Comment: why do you test for dot(x,u)~=0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call `x` your unit vector. Call `u = (1,0,0)`. If `dot(u,x) ~= 0`, then take `u = (0,1,0)`. Then, `y = x ^ u` and `z = x ^ y`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I used you solution with small modification: I put `u = (-x1, x0, x2)` to avoid the if. It should work as long as vectors `(x0,x1,x2)` and `(-x1,x0,x2)` are linearly independent, which, intuitively, seems to be the case (and a test on huge random data set supports it).

Comment: I disagree on your `u` vector choice: `dot( (x0,x1,x2), (-x1,x0,x2) ) = -x0.x1 + x0.x1 + x2.x2 = x2.x2`. So this does work only if `x2 != 0`. I don't think it is safe to use that vector.

Comment: No, I use the **u** vector only to help me calculate **y** and **z** like this: `u = (-x1, x0, x2); y = x ^ u; z = y ^ u` so I don't need it to be perpendicular to **x**, only linearly independent.

Comment: Hm, now I actually did some math only to see that my choice of linearly independent vector fails when both `x0` and `x1` are zero. Seems there is no way around that `if`...

Comment: No. Your `u` vector choice fails when x2 is equal to zero. I still think my `if` test with `u=X` or `u=Y` is the most reliable.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of Tibur's if, you can get a slight improvement by using a cheap(er) mul+float cast

```
y = x ^ u
y.z += float(y==0); // this changes a zero-vector into (0,0,1)
z = x ^ y
```

Doing a vector-compare after the cross product gives you a more stable solution than checking if u == x, the float cast depends on your architecture, but works in most compilers/platforms.

Basically this kind of base function will always have a singularity when x is co-linear with u, so try to pick u wisely from the context, remember that u does not have to be a constant. In most cases you can choose u to coincide with a trivial case so you smooth out the singularity and keep your overall transform stable.